# How to make SVN checkout faster on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, java, svn, eclipse

All my projects sum up to a total size of 485 MB. I need *check-out* (create workspace in eclipse from SVN with SVN eclipse plugin) frequently.

It only takes between 4 to 7 minutes in my linux VM, but on Windows it is taking 45 minutes to 1 and half hours.

I am using the same version of eclipse in both cases, same set and same versions of plugins, same version of java.

I'd like to know what I could try to make it faster. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the "check-out" takes this long? Or could it be that its eclipse automatically building your workspace? Have you tried disabling auto-build and just measure the check-out time?

Comment: Do you have antivirus?

Comment: Disable antivirus (at least for workspace directory) and give it a try again. You can also disable automagic content indexing on the whole drive containing the workspace.

Comment: Why do you need to "checkout frequently"? That is a rather unusual use-case - normally you checkout once, then keep the checkout. If you explain why you need this, we can probably help better.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue on SVN where checkout are slower on Windows than Unix. 
They explain the root cause; files are copied and renamed a lot during the initial checkout and it is done in a slow way on Windows.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-4450
Vote for the issue so the svn people know we have a problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the transfer rate issue is caused by on-access antivirus scanner or the firewall of the antivirus. Windows' Indexing Service can also be the cause here.

- I suggest disabling the antivirus to see whether it solves the issue. Please note that "disabling" some antiviruses does not disable them completely (e.g. firewall or on-access scanner will still be active). It makes sense to temporarily remove the antivirus and check the transfer rate again.
- It's recommended to add directories where you store your repositories and working copies to the exclusion list of the antivirus and indexing services. Do this.